# Printing Qt variables

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qdebug

I'm programming in Qt, but I'm more accustomed to PHP.

So with that in mind, how do I 'echo' or 'print' out the contents of a QStringList or QString to ensure the contents are as expected?

I'm building a GUI application. Is there anyway to print the contents?

Obviously in PHP, you can print_r on an array, is there anything similar for a QStringList?
And echo a variable, again, anything similar to QString?

I can provide code if needs be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QStringList myStringList{"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
    qDebug() << myStringList;
    QString myString = "Hello World!";
    qDebug() << myString;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = print-qstringlist
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && (n)make
```

#### Output

```
("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
"Hello World!"
```

If you need to drop the noisy brackets and double quotes generated by qDebug, you are free to either use QTextStream with custom printing or simply fall back to the standard cout with custom printing.

Comment: I included the QDebug and used the code you provided in the cpp. Perfect. I didn't need to alter the pro file...what are you adding in there that I need?

Comment: It worked without adding the pro file entries, so I was wondering what the TARGET = print-qstringlist is doing? Awesome answer thanks!

Comment: @Luke: yeah, if you do not specify the `TARGET` variable, the generated executable will be called based on the parent folder name.